# DELETE em SQL não executa

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou a tentar apagar linhas de uma base de dados SQL Express, mas infelizmente não o consigo fazer. A query é daquelas mesmo básicas, mas depois de executa-la fico com a mensagem de '**executing query**' no SQL Server Management Studio indefinidamente, mas nunca acaba.

A query é a seguinte:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: A tabela tem algum gatilho? Ou então ela está sendo usada por outro processo?

Comment: Tens de ver se tens outras sessões no management studio com operações pendentes a bloquear o delete. Experimenta clicar no icone "Activity Monitor" (Ctrl+Alt + A) e ve o separador Processes, e lá vês quem te está a bloquear

Comment: não sei o que é gatilho, pode dar-me uma luz?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso eram operações pendentes que estavam a atrasar a execução da query, obrigado pela sugestão, desconhecia o 'Activity Monitor', mt top!

Comment: Sempre às ordens... :)  Ps: marca como respondida

Comment: @RenatoAfonso para que possa marcar como respondida você tem transformar o seu comentário em resposta.

Comment: @ihavenokia trigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens de ver se tens outras sessões no management studio com operações pendentes a bloquear o delete. Experimenta clicar no ícone `Activity Monitor` ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> e vê o separador Processes, e lá vês quem te está a bloquear